# Detect that Java file doesn't compile using subprocess.call

Tags: java, python, javac

I have a program that complies java files in a given the directory. I want a little error message to come up if nothing is compiled. Right now it is simply blank

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os.path,subprocess

print('in main')

directoryContents = os.listdir('.')

for fn in directoryContents:
    if fn.rfind(".java") != -1:
        print ("found a java file named " + fn)
        subprocess.check_call(['javac', fn])    
        java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(fn)
        className = fn[0: fn.rfind(".java")]
        print ("classname is " + className)
        print ("Compiled:")
        cmd = ['java',  className]
                subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
        print ("\n")
```

How do i detect that nothing has been printed to the console?

Comment: It's not even printing `in main` right?

Comment: No. That was a part of my starter code.

Comment: Thus you are unable to run your code. You should save your code as py file and run it from command line to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
directoryContents = os.listdir('.')

for fn in directoryContents:
    print fn, fn.rfind(".java")
```

and run your file like this in your commandline:

```
python file.py
```

There should be some output. If there is no, you are unable to run your code.

Comment: Im confused. Where should I place my code to compile it? Will it not work if there is nothing to compile? I need this to work with about 30 java files all of which may of may not have output.

Comment: You are unable to run your python code. If there is nothing to compile your code will at least print `in main` since you have run this line before checking java files. If there is nothing to compile your code won't give any error, but if there are java files; even if `javac` fails your code should print the file name.

Comment: What do you mean unable? I am able to get the output of the java files. It is a py file. I tried python ISS.py in terminal and got the error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` although Im positive that is the name. Im new to python, sorry.

Comment: You should be in the same directory with your `py` file. You can achieve this using `cd` command. After entering same directory check if the file exists by `ls` or `dir` command. If you are using windows use `dir` else it's most probably `ls` then run `python ISS.py`

Comment: Ok I got a list of different directories but nothing on compiling my Java files

Comment: Try your code. Mine was trying to understand what was happening. Your code will be just fine.

Comment: Ok it works. Any suggestion on detecting if there is output or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43216/discussion-between-scriptmonster-and-tanner-quigley)